# Split() TypeError in Python

Tags: python

I ran a Python program and I am getting the following error as below:

```
   File :...,line ...,in <module>  
   results = parse_file(text, ['stderr'], ['ERROR', 'WARN'])
  
   Fie :....,line ...,in parse_file
   all_containers=re.split('^Container:container_',text,flags=re.MULTILINE)
   TypeError: split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flags'
```

Below is my code:

```
def parse_file(text,filter_log_types=None,filter_content_types=None):
    full_text_lines=text.split('\n')

    results=[]

    all_containers=re.split('^Container:container_',text,flags=re.MULTILINE)

    for item in all_containers[1:]:
        data=parse_container(item, full_text_lines, filter_log_types, filter_content_types)
        results.append(data)

    return results 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = open("lg.txt").read()
    results = parse_file(text, ['stderr'], ['ERROR', 'WARN'])
```

I am using Python 2.6.6. Please help me to sort out this error. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Python 2.6's re.split() doesn't have the 'flags' kwargs as noted here: https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/re.html

Comment: Is there any alternate for that ?So that I can implement it in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **flags** keyword argument was added in [python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=split#re.split) version, so it raises an error in your code

Try to use [re.compile()](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/re.html#re.compile) in combination with split()

```
all_containers=re.compile('^Container:container_',flags=re.MULTILINE).split(text)
```